# SQL 2012 Synchronization

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I need to know how I would go about synchronizing to identical databases, if changes are made in DB1, DB2 will sync with DB1 and if changes are made to DB2, DB1 will sync with DB2. The databases will do a sync every hour.

I will be using two servers with Microsoft SQL 2012.

Please may someone guide me in using the correct setup and technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe only way to accomplish that with sql server,is Replication

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Comment: Will this require configurations in SQL server management studio or would I have to programmatically do it within Visual Studio?

Comment: This is sql server confugiration,if you want to use application sync you could try Microsoft Sync Framework !

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx) may be of use for you. Please visit the [get started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx) page.

Also, SQL Server has [Sync services](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15784) which allow you to connect and synchronize two databases.

[SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) is another option. You may also have a look at the [Replication Developers' guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147384%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).